# Find the first value in larger column greater than or equal to each value in shorter search column

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have been trying to find a vectorized way to get the index of the first value in a large column (> 500k rows) greater than or equal to each value in a shorter column (~ 9k rows).

Currently im looping through each value in the shorter column and comparing it with the entire larger column. Number of loops = length of shorter column.

```py
np.random.seed(2)

veclong = np.random.randint(0, 1000, 100000)
vecshort = np.random.randint(0, 1000, 500)
dfShort=pd.DataFrame(data=vecshort/10000, columns=['Short'])
dfLong=pd.DataFrame(data=veclong/10000, columns=['Long'])

c1=len(dfShort)

out2=[];
for n1 in range(c1):
    val=dfShort['Short'].iloc[n1]
    dfAns=dfLong[dfLong>=val].dropna()
    ans=dfAns['Long'].iloc[0]
    idx=dfAns.index[0]
    out=[ans,idx]
    out2.extend([out])

out2=np.asarray(out2)
dfShort['Location']=out2[:,1]
dfShort['Value']=out2[:,0]
```

Comment: show us some sample data ?

Comment: I added some sample code above, runtime increases quite a bit with vector length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider the following:

```
def myfunc(x):
    try:    
        return dfLong[dfLong.Long>=x].index[0]
    except:
        return None

dfShort['Location'] = dfShort.Short.apply(lambda x: myfunc(x))
dfShort['Value'] = dfShort.Location.apply(lambda x: dfLong.iloc[x, 0] if x!= None else None)
print(dfShort.head())
```

**Output**

```
+----+---------+-----------+--------+
|    | Short   | Location  | Value  |
+----+---------+-----------+--------+
| 0  | 0.0636  |       10  | 0.0674 |
| 1  | 0.0876  |       27  | 0.0938 |
| 2  | 0.0799  |       16  | 0.0831 |
| 3  | 0.0977  |       95  | 0.0997 |
| 4  | 0.0602  |       10  | 0.0674 |
+----+---------+-----------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks @Sebastien D, this implementation is signifigantly faster than mine! Original = 3.20423 secs vs New = 0.768056 secs.

Comment: Hi @Sebastien D, on further thought i'm wondering.... is there a way to end the search at the first >= value and not search the whole long array... that may save some more time

Comment: You mean in `dfLong[dfLong.Long>=x].index[0]` ? Not to sure about that.